# Spark SQL: Extract String before a certain character

Tags: sql, string, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a string in a column in a table where I want to extract all the characters before the first dot(.). Here is the input:

```
Place
Chicago.City.XXXX
Denver.City.XXX.YYY
Dallas.City.FFF.DDD.GGGG
```

Expected output:

```
City
CHICAGO
DENVER
DALLAS
```

I am trying this:

```sql
select left(upper(Place), charindex('.', upper(Place))-1) as City from Table
```

But I am getting the error

> Message : AnalysisException: "Undefined function: 'charindex'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Spark SQL there's [`substring_index`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#substring_index)

```sql
select substring_index(upper(Place), '.', 1) as City from Table
```

Answer (score 0):

SparkSQL does not support [charindex()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/search.html?q=charindex).
This should work:

```
select upper(split_part(Place, '.', 1)) as City from Table
```

Comment: It gives below error. Undefined function: 'split_part'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.

Comment: How are you querying the table?